# How to pass data from the POST request to the request to external service?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a POST request to `index.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btn-calc").click(function () {
       let cityValue = $("#delivery_city").val(),
           weightValue = $("#weight").val();

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "index.php",
           data: {
               city: cityValue,
               weight: weightValue
           },
           success: function () {
               console.log("Success")
           },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Fail")
            }
       })
   })
});
```

It sends the `.delivery_calc` data to PHP script called `index.php`. In the `index.php` I need to realize the request to the external service. The request must be like this:

> exercise.develop.maximaster.ru/service/delivery/?city=Тула&weight=150

That is, you see the data from the POST request. How to pass it to the request to the external service? Thank you in advance.

P.S. At this moment `index.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require("read_cache.php");

$content = file_get_contents('cities.html');
$city_array = json_decode($content, true);

$price = file_get_contents('http://exercise.develop.maximaster.ru/service/delivery/');
$priceMsg = json_decode($price, true);
?>
```

Comment: @Alexander `$price = file_get_contents("http://exercise.develop.maximaster.ru/service/delivery/?city=$_POST['city']&weight=$_POST['weight']");`

Comment: See php http_build_query.

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz This is a little bit insecure without `urlencode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prepare a url together with query string you can use function called [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

You can use it this way:

```
$queryString = http_build_query([
    'city' => $_POST['city'],
    'weight' => $_POST['weight']
]);
$price = file_get_contents('http://exercise.develop.maximaster.ru/service/delivery/?'.$queryString);
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work: "Warning: file_get_contents(http://exercise.develop.maximaster.ru/service/delivery/?) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Comment: Are you sure you are doing it right? I see there is no query string after `?` in your url. Are you submitting your form correctly?

Comment: Now `index.php` looks like this:

    `$queryString = http_build_query(array(
       'city' => $_POST['city'],
       'weight' => $_POST['weight']
    ));
    $price = 
 file_get_contents('http://exercise.develop.maximaster.ru/service/delivery/?'.$queryString);
    $priceMsg = json_decode($price, true);`